# Using fabric inside a container to deploy an application

Tags: jenkins, ssh, fabric

I am using a Jenkins setup where every slave is an ephemera docker container, the Jenkins user connects to the container/slave through an ssh connection. At the end of the Jenkins pipeline, if all tests and analysis are good, the app is deployed to a staging environment using fabric script.

Fabfile:

```
@task
def deploy():
    require('context', provided_by=(stage,prod,pprod))

    #figure out the package and file names and version
    file_name = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.tar.gz')][0]
    package_name = file_name.split('.')[0]#os.path.splitext(fullname)[0]

    setup_ssh_agent()

    # upload the package to the temporary folder on the server
    with cd(env.release_dir):
      put('{}'.format(file_name), '.')   

def setup_ssh_agent():
  local('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa')
```

I get this error:

```
fab stage deploy
Agent pid 808
Identity added: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa (rsa w/o comment)
/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py:83: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
[stage.mycompany.com] Login password for 'jenkins': [stage.mycompany.com] Executing task 'deploy'
[localhost] local: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
*****upload the package to the releases directory on the provision server*****
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 756, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 386, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 276, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 173, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/nt-release-pipeline-eokouya-5KGNK7CKO2VEM6GERMMTBRTMUZI3G3LDQB4ZKJF7JVTBVSTTW22Q/fabfile.py", line 72, in deploy
    put('{}'.format(file_name), '.')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 683, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 346, in put
    ftp = SFTP(env.host_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/sftp.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.ftp = connections[host_string].open_sftp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 159, in __getitem__
    self.connect(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in connect
    user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 565, in connect
    password = prompt_for_password(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 648, in prompt_for_password
    new_password = _password_prompt(password_prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 620, in _password_prompt
    return getpass.getpass(prompt.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 83, in unix_getpass
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 118, in fallback_getpass
    return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 135, in _raw_input
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

The ssh identity is authorized on the staging server, I have tested ssh connection to that machine using that identity on my Linux pc and it works, I have to run that script from my machine using that ssh key and it works as well.

If anyone has had this problem, I would love to know how you solved it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the server where are you gonna deploy has jenkins user ssh keys.

It looks like function setup_ssh_agent() doesn't do its job
The possible reason jenkins user has no .ssh/id_rsa .ssh/id_rsa/pub files

then you have to create them on your local machine for user jenkins

`sudo su jenkins`

`cd`

`mkdir .ssh`

`cd .ssh`

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

copy id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to target server